# cpprestsdk(casablanca) json преобразовать в вектор байтов

Tags: c++, json, vector, byte

Всем здрасте, использую [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) для напиания http клиента, стоит задача преобразовать такой json в `std::vector<unsigned char>`

```
    web::json::value obj;
    obj[U("1")] = web::json::value(U("123"));
    obj[U("2")] = web::json::value(U("321"));
```

Можно ли это сдлеать средствами библиотеки? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте метод `serialize()`, он вернет ваш json в виде string, а дальше уже заворачивать это в вектор:

```
auto stdstring = obj.serialize();
const char* data = stdstring.data();
// инициализируем vector из data ...
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую.